# XAML small Multicolumn List inside LiesView Element

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App I have a `ListView`, inside the `ItemTemplate` I have to show a text-only list with 3 columns.

The first idea was to use a `GroupedListView`, but in this case all subentries are selectable separately.
That is not what I want. The `ListView` Item should appear as one selectable element.

The Second idea I found on my research is to add `Gridview` rows by code, but this would break my MVVM concept. I need a solution which works with databinding only.

The third thing I sometimes read is: cascade a `ListView` inside the `ListView`. But mostly the answer to such idea is: "never do this".

Any other idea what I can do for this?
What I want is something like this:

```
ListView Entry 1
     04:13      Jhonny           3,24$
     09:45      Some Long Nam... 8,23$
     14:42      Mike             5,45$
----------------------------------------
ListView Entry 2
     07:13      Jhonny           3,24$
     11:22      Some Long Nam... 8,23$
     18:42      Mike             5,45$
----------------------------------------
ListView Entry 3
     05:13      Jhonny           3,24$
     15:45      Some Long Nam... 8,23$
     19:42      Mike             5,45$
----------------------------------------
```

Always the whole `Listview` Entry should be selectable as one element.

Comment: Could you share a minimal xaml ?

Comment: does every "group" always contain 3 lines?

Comment: Do you want something like this : https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/getting-started

Comment: @Jason: No, number of lines differ. The data comes from a List<dataStruct>

Comment: I think Grouped is your best option.  If the user taps on a row, you can still act on the entire group, not just the individual row

Comment: See my answer @andrehulle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you could use the BindableLayout. You didn't specify the Type, so i made a dummy type.
View:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Time}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Amount}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                  
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Codebehind:

```
 public ObservableCollection<GroupItem> GroupItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GroupItem>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        GroupItem item1 = new GroupItem();
        item1.Title = "Entry 1";
        item1.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "10:13", Name = "Johnny", Amount = "10,24$" });
        item1.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "12:11", Name = "Some long name that will be truncated", Amount = "20,14$" });
        item1.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "10:13", Name = "Mike", Amount = "14,27$" });
        GroupItems.Add(item1);  

        GroupItem item2 = new GroupItem();
        item2.Title = "Entry 2";
        item2.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "11:13", Name = "Finn", Amount = "10,24$" });
        item2.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "14:11", Name = "Some long name that will be truncated", Amount = "20,14$" });
        GroupItems.Add(item2);
        
        GroupItem item3 = new GroupItem();
        item3.Title = "Entry 3";
        item3.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "11:13", Name = "Finn", Amount = "10,24$" });
        item3.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "14:11", Name = "Some long name that will be truncated", Amount = "20,14$" });
        item3.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "14:11", Name = "Martin", Amount = "50,15$" });
        item3.Entries.Add(new Entry { Time = "14:11", Name = "Elon musk", Amount = "30,14$" });
        GroupItems.Add(item3);
    }

    public class GroupItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; } = new List<Entry>();
    }

    public class Entry 
    {
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

This gives you the possibility of a dynamic amount of rows, and every group is selectable.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank a lot! This is 100% what I was looking for.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad i could help